# WebClient Rest call is throwing NPE for Builder

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, webclient, reactive

This is my Service class snippet and I am trying to write a test for this class. While writing tests for some reasons, my builder is throwing NPE. I am using webclient builder to set up my base-url.

```
public class ServiceWithConstructor {
    private final WebClient webClientForEmployee;

    public ServiceWithConstructor(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        webClientForEmployee = builder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8081").build();
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Employee[]> getEmployees() {

        Employee[] employeeArray = webClientForEmployee
                .get()
                .uri("/employees")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Employee[].class)
                .block()

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(employeeArray);

}
```

This is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceWithConstructorTest {

    @Mock
    WebClient webClientForEmployee;
    @Mock
    WebClient.Builder builder;
    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpecMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock;

    ServiceWithConstructor serviceWithConstructor;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        serviceWithConstructor = new ServiceWithConstructor(builder.baseUrl("/base-url"));
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
        // FAILS
    void getEmployeesShouldReturnList() {
        when(webClientForEmployee.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpecMock);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpecMock.uri("/all-employees")).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
        when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
        when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(Employee[].class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(employeeArrayResponseMock()));


        ResponseEntity<Employee[]>> actual = serviceWithConstructor.getEmployees();
        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.is2xxSuccessful(), actual.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
    }
```

And it fails with this stack trace saying builder is null. I am not sure why is builder null, when I have mocked it.

````
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.baseUrl(String)" because "builder" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.baseUrl(String)" because "builder" is null
    at com.kbi.experienceapi.service.ServiceWithConstructor.<init>(ServiceWithConstructor.java:19)
    at com.kbi.experienceapi.service.ServiceWithConstructorTest.setUp(ServiceWithConstructorTest.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to create stubs for `WebClient.Builder` before invoking the `ServiceWithConstructor` constructor in  `@BeforeEach`

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {

    //create stubs
    when(builder.baseUrl(anyString())).theReturn(builder);
    when(builder.build()).theReturn(webClientForEmployee);

    serviceWithConstructor = new ServiceWithConstructor(builder.baseUrl("/base-url"));
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}
```